# PythonでGMAILの本文を日本語で取得したい

Tags: python, gmail

Pyhonでimaplibのライブラリーを使って、Gmailを取得しています。
GMAILのボックスモデル（ボーダー）から本文を取得したいですが、下記のように本文のみ文字化けしてしまいます。
差出人、タイトルの取得は特に問題なく取得できます。

文字コードを**iso-2022-jp**、**UTF-8**、**SHIFT JIS**、**ascii**へ変更しても同じ本文のみ文字化けします。

文字化けしない方法ありますでしょうか。
もし分かる方がいましたら、教えて頂けると幸いです。

CODE

```
import imaplib, re, email, six, dateutil.parser

mail=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)    #SMTPは993,POPは995
mail.login('example@co.jp','12134')
mail.select()   #メールボックスの選択

#UNSEEN未読メールを読み込む
# type,data=mail.search(None,'UNSEEN') #メールボックス内にあるすべてのデータを取得ALL

#特定のメールUNSEEN未読メールを読み込む
term = u"【Test".encode("utf-8")
mail.literal = term
type,data=mail.search("utf-8", "UNSEEN SUBJECT")

for i in data[0].split():   #data分繰り返す
 ok,x=mail.fetch(i,'RFC822')    #メールの情報を取得
 #mail文字コード指定
 ms=email.message_from_string(x[0][1].decode('iso-2022-jp'))    #パースして取得

 #差出人を取得
 ad=email.header.decode_header(ms.get('From'))
 ms_code=ad[0][1]
 if(ms_code!=None):
  address=ad[0][0].decode(ms_code)
  address+=ad[1][0].decode(ms_code)
 else:
  address=ad[0][0]

 #タイトルを取得
 sb=email.header.decode_header(ms.get('Subject'))
 ms_code=sb[0][1]
 if(ms_code!=None):
  sbject=sb[0][0].decode(ms_code)
 else:
  ms_code=sb[1][1]
  sbject=sb[1][0].decode(ms_code)

 #本文を取得
 if ms.is_multipart():
  for payload in ms.get_payload():
   if payload.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
    body = payload.get_payload()

   else:
    if ms.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
     body = ms.get_payload()

 #メールの日時を取得
 time = dateutil.parser.parse(ms.get('Date')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")[:-1]
 time_comment = dateutil.parser.parse(ms.get('Date')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

 print(time)

 #出力
 print(sbject)
 print(address)
 print(body)
```

出力結果

```
2021-11-05 09:2
Test
example@co.jp

VEVTVOOAgA0KVEVTVOODgeOCseODg+ODiOOBp+OBmeOAgg==
```

お手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

[image: 実際のGMAILの本文になります。]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 エンコードされているだけです。得られたメッセージボディの文字列をデコードすれば完了です。

簡単な例：

```
import base64

print(base64.b64decode(
    b'VEVTVOOAgA0KVEVTVOODgeOCseODg+ODiOOBp+OBmeOAgg=='
).decode())
```

出力：

```
TEST　
TESTチケットです。
```

Comment: 早速回答ありがとうございます。上記の方法で問題なくできました。